# Proof of definite integral $\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\sin(2n+1)x}{\sin x}dx=\frac\pi2$ using induction

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, induction

Prove by induction or otherwise that $$\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\sin(2n+1)x}{\sin x}dx=\frac\pi2$$ for every integer $n\ge0$.

How to prove the above question?

Can it be proved without using induction?

Comment: Well I imagine [Weierstrass substitution](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WeierstrassSubstitution.html) should work, but its probably easier by induction and good practice. What have you tried?

Comment: Maybe you could use expression of $\sin(2n+1)x/\sin x$ obtained from this question (or other questions linked there): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/225941/proving-sum-limits-k-0n-coskx-frac12-frac-sin-frac2n12x

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$I_n = \int_0^{\pi/2} \dfrac{\sin(2n+1)x}{\sin(x)}dx$$ We then have
$$I_{n+1} - I_n = \int_0^{\pi/2} \dfrac{2 \sin(x)\cos(2(n+1)x)}{\sin(x)} dx = 2\int_0^{\pi/2} \cos(2(n+1)x) dx = 0$$ for $n \neq -1$.
Hence,
$$I_n = I_0 = \dfrac{\pi}2$$
Essentially, we are saying that $\dfrac{dI_n}{dn} = 0$, where the derivative is to be interpreted in discrete sense and concluding that $I_n$ must be a constant.

Answer (score 2):

For $n=0$, the equality is trivial. Then note that:
$$
\int_0^{\frac\pi2} \frac{\sin(2n+3)x}{\sin x}dx=\int_0^{\frac\pi2} \frac{\cos 2x\sin(2n+1)x}{\sin x}dx+\int_0^{\frac\pi2} \frac{\sin 2x\cos(2n+1)x}{\sin x}dx
$$
And use $\cos 2x=1-2\sin^2x$ and $\sin2x=2\cos x\sin x$. You get:
$$
\int_0^{\frac\pi2} \frac{\sin(2n+3)x}{\sin x}dx=\int_0^{\frac\pi2} \frac{\sin(2n+1)x}{\sin x}dx-2\int_0^{\frac\pi2} \cos(2n+2)x dx.
$$
Now it is not difficult to see that $\int_0^{\frac\pi2} \cos(2n+2)x dx=0$. This will constitute the induction step.