# Using Partial Summation to evaluate a series

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, summation

$$S = \sum_{x=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(x)}{x}$$

Using partial summation. Obviously,

$$S = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{x=1}^{n} \frac{\sin(x)}{x}$$

Partial Summation:

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{N} a(n) f(n) & = \sum_{n=1}^{N} f(n) (A(n)- A(n-1)) = \sum_{n=1}^{N} A(n) f(n) - \sum_{n=1}^{N} A(n-1) f(n)\\
& = \sum_{n=1}^{N} A(n)f(n) - \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} A(n) f(n+1)\\
& = A(N)f(N) - A(0) f(1) - \sum_{n=1}^{N-1} A(n) (f(n+1)-f(n))
\end{align*}

But how do I apply it? What is $A(n)$? I am confused?

Comment: Look up Dirichlet test in Wikipedia

Comment: @Alex, but how will that helped (I already knew about this)?

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe I confused something...perhaps this could help: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/225941/proving-sum-limits-k-0n-coskx-frac12-frac-sin-frac2n12x

Answer (score 1):

$A\left(n\right)$
  in your case can be$$\sum_{n=1}^{N}\sin\left(n\right)=\sin\left(\frac{N+1}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{N}{2}\right)\textrm{cosec}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$$
 an so $$f\left(n\right)=\frac{1}{n}$$
 or$$\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{n}=H_{N}$$
 where $H_{N}$
  is the $N$
 -th armonic number, and$$f\left(n\right)=\sin\left(n\right)$$
 but I think there is a more rapid way using Fourier series. In fact we have, for $0<x<2\pi$
 $$\frac{\pi-x}{2}=\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{\sin\left(nx\right)}{n}.$$