# Integral calculus sine functions: $\frac{1}{2\pi }\int_{-\pi }^{\pi }\frac{\sin\left((n+1/2)\,x\right)}{\sin\left(x/2\right)}\,dx = 1$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis, definite-integrals

For an integer, $n$, how do I show the following?

$$
\frac{1}{2\pi }\int_{-\pi }^{\pi }\frac{\sin\left((n+1/2)\,x\right)}{\sin\left(x/2\right)}\,dx = 1.
$$

Can I use induction?

Comment: Name this integral as $I_n$ Try finding out $I_n-I_{n-1}$

Comment: show that your integral is equal to $1$ if $n$ is a positive integer

Answer (score 11):

To use induction, first establish a base case.  If $n=0$, then we see trivially that

$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi \frac{\sin\left((n+1/2)x\right)}{\sin(x/2)}\,dx=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi \frac{\sin\left(x/2\right)}{\sin(x/2)}\,dx=1$$

Next, we assume that for some integer $N\ge 1$ we have

$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi \frac{\sin\left((N+1/2)x\right)}{\sin(x/2)}\,dx=1$$

We now examine the integral for $n=N+1$.  Proceeding, we have

$$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi \frac{\sin\left((N+1+1/2)x\right)}{\sin(x/2)}\,dx&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi \frac{\sin\left((N+1/2)x\right)+2\cos((N+1)x)\sin(x/2)}{\sin(x/2)}\,dx\\\\
&=\color{blue}{\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi \frac{\sin\left((N+1/2)x\right)}{\sin(x/2)}\,dx}+\color{red}{\frac1\pi \int_{-\pi}^\pi \cos((N+1)x)\,dx}\\\\
&=\color{blue}{1}+\color{red}{0}\\\\
&=1
\end{align}$$

as was to be shown!

Comment: Well done and I like this neat answer+1).

Comment: @xpaul Thank you!  Much appreciated.

Comment: Good stuff. Good stuff.

Comment: @c650 Thank you!  Much appreciative.

Answer (score 7):

Observe [that](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/225941/proving-sum-limits-k-0n-coskx-frac12-frac-sin-frac2n12x)

$$\frac{\sin\left(n+\frac12\right)x}{\sin\frac x2}=2\sum_{k=0}^n\cos kx+1\implies$$

$$\int_{-\pi}^\pi\frac{\sin\left(n+\frac12\right)x}{\sin\frac x2}dx=2\sum_{k=0}^n\int_{-\pi}^\pi\cos kx\,dx+2\pi=2\pi$$

and we're done.

Comment: Wrong sign: the first $-1$ should be a $+1$. The Dirichlet kernel is concentrated around the origin and is positive in a neighbourhood of the origin, hence the integral has to be $>0$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Good catch, I messed that sign from the first line. Thanks, editing.

Comment: Heh, and I use this in the opposite manner to calculate a sum of cosines...

Answer (score 7):

You are integrating the [Dirichlet kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_kernel)
$$ D_n(x) = \sum_{k=-n}^{n}e^{ikx} = 1+2\sum_{k=1}^{n}\cos(kx) = \frac{\sin\left((n+1/2)x\right)}{\sin(x/2)} \tag{1}$$
where the last equality follows from creative telescoping, since
$$ 2\cos(kx)\sin(x/2) = \sin\left((k+1/2)x\right)-\sin\left((k-1/2)x\right).\tag{2}$$
As a by-product of $(1)$,
$$ \int_{0}^{2\pi}D_n(x)\,dx = 2\pi+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\cos(kx)\,dx = 2\pi.\tag{3} $$

Comment: @mathd: see the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Lebesgue_lemma