# Let $I_n=\int_0^\pi\frac{\sin(n+\frac12)x}{\sin \frac x2}dx$ where $n\in W$. If $\sum_{n=1}^{100}I_n=k\pi$, find the total number of divisors of $k$.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

> Let $I_n=\displaystyle\int_0^\pi\frac{\sin(n+\frac12)x}{\sin \frac x2}dx$ where $n\in\mathbb W$. If $\sum_{n=1}^{100}I_n=k\pi$, find the total number of divisors of $k$.

$$I_1+I_2+I_3+...+I_{100}=k\pi\\\displaystyle\int_0^\pi\frac{\sin\frac{3x}2+\sin\frac{5x}2+...+\sin\frac{201x}2}{\sin \frac x2}dx=k\pi$$

Using the formula, $\sin\alpha+\sin(\alpha+\beta)+...\sin(\alpha+(n-1)\beta)=\dfrac{\sin\frac{n\beta}2}{\sin\frac\beta2}\sin(\alpha+(n-1)\frac\beta2)$, I get

$$\displaystyle\int_0^\pi\frac{\sin50x\sin51x}{\sin^2\frac x2}dx=k\pi\\\implies\displaystyle\int_0^\pi\frac{\cos x-\cos101x}{1+\cos x}=k\pi$$

Not able to proceed next.

I have found a different solution [online](https://www.sarthaks.com/547777/find-the-value-of-sin-n-1-2-x-sin-x-2-dx-for-x-0), but I wish to end what I have started.

Comment: What is $\mathbb{W}$?

Comment: @RounakSarkar I have posted the question verbatim. I think they meant Whole Numbers.

Comment: $W$ is to be replaced by $\mathbb N$.

Comment: Consider this solution : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2037750 showing that, in the background of your expressions, you have the Dirichlet kernel.

Comment: @JeanMarie $n$ can be $0$ as well.

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks for the link.