# $\sum_{k=0}^{n} Re(\cos(kx))=\sum_{k=0}^{n} Re(\cos(x)^k)$?

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry

I recently saw the following ([Proving $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\cos(kx)=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sin(\frac{2n+1}{2}x)}{2\sin(x/2)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/225941/proving-sum-limits-k-0n-coskx-frac12-frac-sin-frac2n12x)), and I saw that they said the following is true.

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} Re(\cos(kx))=\sum_{k=0}^{n} Re(\cos(x)^k)$$

At the moment I believe this to be false, I tried a small case with, $n=2$ and $x=pi/4$. Which gives $$\sum_{k=0}^{2} Re(\cos(k\frac{\pi}{4}))=\sum_{k=0}^{2} Re(\cos(\frac{\pi}{4})^k),$$
and this is not true.

The most I could show was, $\cos(kx)=Re((\cos(x)+i\sin(x))^k)$.

Could any one show me why the person said the first equation is true?

Comment: Probably because they were confusing $\cos$ with $\exp$. Or maybe they momentarily believed ${\rm Re}((\cos+i\sin)^k)={\rm Re}(\cos^k)$ because ${\rm Re}(\cos+i\sin)=\cos$.

Comment: Yea, I'm surprised nobody had caught that mistake then.

Comment: Good point for you and $\to +1$