# How to prove $\sin x+\frac{\sin 2x}{2}+\frac{\sin 3x}{3}+\cdots$ is positive?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, induction

Let $0<x<\pi$. $n$ be a natural number.

How to prove

$$\sin x+\frac{\sin 2x}{2}+\frac{\sin 3x}{3}+\cdots+ \frac{\sin nx}{n}>0$$

Comment: Hint: Try by induction.

Comment: could you explain

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/175768/show-1-2-sum-n-1n-cos-n-x-frac-sin-n-1-2-x-sin-fracx2

Comment: @Ivan: Induction? How?

Comment: Well you can easily prove this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/175768/show-1-2-sum-n-1n-cos-n-x-frac-sin-n-1-2-x-sin-fracx2?lq=1 by induction, so i though you could prove that by induction, maybe I am wrong.

Comment: @Ivan - In the link you assume the identity for $n-1$ and use trigonometric identities to add to the $n-1$ terms and show that that the identity is true for $n$ terms (hence for all natural numbers). But in this question the induction hypothesis will only tell you that the sum of the $n-1$ terms is positive - but with no knowledge of how much, after adding a negative term to it (the $n$-th term may be negative) you wouldn't know if the sum is now positive or negative

Comment: The Maple command $evalc(Re(sum(sin(k*x)/k, k = 1 .. infinity)))$ produces $$-1/2\,\arctan \left( -\sin \left( x \right) ,-\cos \left( x \right) +1
 \right) +1/2\,\arctan \left( \sin \left( x \right) ,-\cos \left( x
 \right) +1 \right)
. $$ See [?arctan](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=invtrig) for info.

Comment: It would be helpful to take a look at the book of Polya and Szego(i.e., the Problems and Theorems in Analysis II Chapter 6, Section 3, No.23-25)

Comment: to y zhao  could you explain, I do not have that book

Comment: They claim and prove that i)The sum $$A(n,x):=\sum_{k=1}^{k=n}\frac {\sin kx} k$$ has the only maximums at $x=\frac \pi {n+1}(2j-1),\ j=1\dots,[\frac {n+1} 2] $ and the only minimums at $x=\frac {2\pi k} {n},\,k = 1 \dots , [\frac {n+1} 2]$ on the interval $[0,\pi]$; ii)The maximum value of $A(n,x)$ on $[0.\pi]$ is reached at  $x=\frac \pi {n+1} $; iii) $$ \lim_{n \to \infty}A\left(n,\frac \pi {n+1}\right)=\int_0^\pi \frac {\sin(x)} x \, dx.$$

Comment: thank you.Then the only extreme values that matter are the minimums.

Comment: how can we derive that the minimums are all positive?

Comment: Look in  Polya and Szego(i.e., the Problems and Theorems in Analysis II Chapter 6, Section 3, No.23-25).

Comment: I do not have that book.

Comment: Could you explain or send me a scan

Comment: Did the book mention how to prove that the minimums are all positive?

Comment: It has been solved in Math.SE, see the following link:

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/376273/inequality-sum-1-le-k-le-n-frac-sin-kxk-ge-0?lq=1

Answer (score 1):

Let $f_n(x)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{\sin{kx}}{k}$.

For $n=1$ it's obvious.

Let $f_n(x)>0$ for any $0<x<\pi.$

It's enough to prove that $f_{n+1}(x)>0.$

Indeed, let $f_{n+1}(x)\leq0$ for some value of $x\in(0,\pi)$.

Since $f_{n+1}$ is a continuous function on $[0,\pi],$ $f_{n+1}(0)=f_{n+1}(\pi)=0,$

there is $x_0\in(0,\pi)$ for which $f_{n+1}$ gets a minimal value and we know that $f_{n+1}(x_0)\leq0.$

Now, $$f'_{n+1}(x_0)=0$$ or
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\cos{kx_0}=0$$ or
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}2\sin\frac{x_0}{2}\cos{kx_0}=0$$ or
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\left(\sin\left(kx_0+\frac{x_0}{2}\right)-\sin\left(kx_0-\frac{x_0}{2}\right)\right)=0$$ or
$$\sin\left(nx_0+\frac{3x_0}{2}\right)=\sin\frac{x_0}{2},$$ which gives:
$$0\geq f_{n+1}(x_0)=f_n(x_0)+\frac{1}{n+1}\sin(n+1)x_0=$$
$$=f_n(x_0)+\frac{1}{n+1}\sin\left(\left(n+\frac{3}{2}\right)x_0-\frac{x_0}{2}\right)=$$
$$=f_n(x_0)+\frac{1}{n+1}\left(\sin\left(n+\frac{3}{2}\right)x_0\cos\frac{x_0}{2}-\cos\left(n+\frac{3}{2}\right)x_0\sin\frac{x_0}{2}\right)=$$
$$=f_n(x_0)+\frac{\sin\frac{x_0}{2}}{n+1}\left(\cos\frac{x_0}{2}-\cos\left(n+\frac{3}{2}\right)x_0\right)=$$
$$=f_n(x_0)+\frac{\sin\frac{x_0}{2}}{n+1}\left(\left|\cos\left(n+\frac{3}{2}\right)x_0\right|-\cos\left(n+\frac{3}{2}\right)x_0\right)\geq f_n(x_0),$$ which is a contradiction and by induction we are done!

Comment: @Martin R Take $x=\frac{\pi}{4(n+1)}$ and see please better my solution.

Comment: Can down-voter explain us why did you do it?

Comment: Since I promised to check it: I think your proof is right (you're not surprised:) but maybe you can make it cleaner -  the lines 6-8 are confusing and unneeded, and you may explain the last equality (where you get the absolute value). Perhaps saying at the beginning that it is by induction might be helpful.

Comment: @user8268 Thank you! We need lines $6-8$ because we want to prove that $f_{n+1}$ gets on $(0,\pi)$ a minimal value. Since $(0,\pi)$ is open it's not always true.

Comment: but... you suppose by contradiction that $f_{n+1}(x)\leq 0$ for some $x\in(0,\pi)$, which does imply that there is a minimum inside - no?

Comment: @user8268 Follows, but we need to prove it. We have a continuous on $(0,\pi)$ function. It's not always true.

Comment: @user8268 Now I see! If $f_{n+1}=0$, so $f'_{n+1}=0$ for $x\in(0,\pi),$ which we want. Tank you!  My reasoning in lines 6-8 is true, but not necessary.